# Adding a style for ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-styles

I want to make a `style` for `ConstraintLayout` but it seem nothing happened.

This is my style :

```
<style name="ConstraintLayoutFragment">
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/margin_border_screen</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/margin_border_screen</item>
</style>
```

This is how I applied the `style` :

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        style="ConstraintLayoutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Maybe I need to put a `parent` in the `style` but I don't found anything for `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I just forget to put a `@style/` :

```
    style="@style/ConstraintLayoutFragment"
```

Comment: (not the downvoter) posting an answer to your own question with a new question inside definitely isn't the way of getting other answers, you should probably just ask a new question :)